# python 3 prints bytestring and says string is of type str?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code I have is from an single-sign-on function

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
import base64

payload = unquote(payload)
print(payload)
print(type(payload))
decoded = base64.decodestring(payload)
```

decodestring is complaining that I gave it a string instead of bytes...

> ```
>   File "/Users/Jeff/Development/langalang/proj/discourse/views.py", line 38, in sso
>     decoded = base64.decodestring(payload)
>   File "/Users/Jeff/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 559, in decodestring
>     return decodebytes(s)
>   File "/Users/Jeff/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 551, in decodebytes
>     _input_type_check(s)
>   File "/Users/Jeff/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 520, in _input_type_check
>     raise TypeError(msg) from err
> TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
> ```

which is fine but when I look at what my print statements printed to the terminal I see this...

```
b'bm9uY2U9NDI5NDg5OTU0NjU4MjAzODkyNTI=\n'
<class 'str'>
```

it seems to be saying it is a string of bytes, but then it says that it is a string.

What is going on here?

if I add a `encode()` to the end of the payload declaration I see this...

```
payload = unquote(payload).encode()

b"b'bm9uY2U9NDQxMTQ4MzIyNDMwNjU3MjcyMDM=\\n'"
<class 'bytes'>
```

EDIT: adding the method that makes the payload

```
@patch("discourse.views.HttpResponseRedirect")
def test_sso_success(self, mock_redirect):
    """Test for the sso view"""

    # Generating a random number, encoding for url, signing it with a hash
    nonce = "".join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(20)])
    # The sso payload needs to be a dict of params
    params = {"nonce": nonce}
    payload = base64.encodestring(urlencode(params).encode())
    print(payload.decode() + " tests")

    key = settings.SSO_SECRET
    h = hmac.new(key.encode(), payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
    signature = h.hexdigest()

    url = reverse("discourse:sso") + "?sso=%s&sig=%s" % (payload, signature)
    req = self.rf.get(url)
    req.user = self.user
    response = sso(req)
    self.assertTrue(mock_redirect.called)
```

Comment: Where exactly is `payload` defined _originally_?

Comment: what is `payload`? How did you get it? Create simple, working example.

Comment: @leaf payload creation function added to post. It is created in a django unittest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `payload` is generate by this `base64.encodestring(s)` which is by documentation is:

> Encode the bytes-like object s, which can contain arbitrary binary
>   data, and return bytes containing the base64-encoded data, with
>   newlines (b'\n') inserted after every 76 bytes of output, and ensuring
>   that there is a trailing newline, as per RFC 2045 (MIME).

Then you do `urllib.parse.unquote` to a byte sequence that consists of ASCII chars. At that moment you got a prefix of `b'` to your string as unquote runs str constructor over payload bytearray. As a request you get a str instead of bytes , which is moreover a not valid base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to be saying it is a string of bytes, but then it says that it is a string.

Looks like you have here string looks like: `"b'bm9uY2U9NDQxMTQ4MzIyNDMwNjU3MjcyMDM=\\n'"` so leading b is not byte literal it is just part of string's value.

So you need to rid off this symbols before pass it to base64 decoder:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote, quote_from_bytes
import base64

payload = unquote(payload)
print(payload[2:-1])
enc = base64.decodebytes(payload[2:-1].encode())
print(enc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The original error allowed to think that, and the display of the encoded string confirms it: your `payload` string **is** a unicode string, which happens to begin with the prefix `"b'"` and ends with a single `"'"`.

Such a string is generally built with a `repr` call:

```
>>> b = b'abc'   # b is a byte string
>>> r = repr(b)  # by construction r is a unicode string
>>> print(r)     # will look like a byte string
b'abc'
>>> print(b)     # what is printed for a true byte string
abc
```

You can revert to a true byte string with `literal_eval`:

```
>>> b2 = ast.literal_eval(r)
>>> type(b2)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b == b2
True
```

But the revert is only a workaround and you should track in your code where you build a *representation* of a byte string.